# best way to monitor versioning - ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I currently have an app that is live.  I want to add a bunch of new functionality to it, but don't want to upload it via heroku until it is completely finished.  The new functionality stuff is quite extensive so it will be done via multiple git branches.

My question is, how do I continue to build out the app while keeping the existing one running and being able to fix minor things here and there on the live site without having the WIP stuff shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out

http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Your issue is resolved by the hot fixes branch.  "Merge"/copy production to the hot fix branch.  Test the change.  When the testing passes, merge the change into production and merge the change into development.

Comment: Thanks for the link Marlin.  What are your thoughts between this post and heroku's staging to manage different environments?  Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familiar with heroku, so I don't know how heroku would affect the process.  I expect it would just be an alternate test environment.  (Not the rails test environment which is for development testing, but an acceptance testing environment.)

Answer (score 1):

You should deploy another copy of your application that will be your testing/staging environment. Deploy to it while you develop. After you're done developing, merge everything to master and deploy to the production env.

Also, read the link that @MarlinPierce posted. It changed my life :)